# HTTP/1.1 disable completely client cache

Tags: java, browser-cache, cache-control, http-1.1, disable-caching

I have several sites that contains sensitive data so **I want to disable client cache completely**. I found there are 3 implementations used for Http/1.1 on google:

- **Implement 1: Set "no-store" with the others**

  ```
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
  ```
- **Implement 2: Set "no-store, no-cache"**

  ```
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache");

  // REASON is "no-cache" already cover this "max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  ```
- **Implement 3: Set "no-store":**

  ```
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");

  // REASON is: "no-store": data is never stored 
  // on both client cache & intermediate caches
  ```

I found this diagram ( Source from google site: [Cache Control Policy Diagram](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en#defining-optimal-cache-control-policy) )

[image: Cache Control Policy Diagram]

**From this diagram, My understanding is Implementation 3 is enough for HTTP/1.1**

Any comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to happen when the user hits the back button in the browser.

If you don't care about that use no-store

If you don't want the previous page displayed, then you need to use must-revalidate too

Comment: Thank you Neil McGuigan!